# how to add icon to a div using the pseudo elements- CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to add an icon as a connector before a div container: something like this:

[image]

This is what I have have (https://jsfiddle.net/kmcursf6/).

```css
.parent {
  border-left: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -20px;
  top: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ff0000;
  width: 20px;
}

.child:last-child::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -21px;
  top: calc(50% + 1px);
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    click to add more
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried this to add that icon:

```
.child::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -20px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

but it doesn't work and it completely throws off what I have. Any ideas how to get there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to create a black circle **and** a horizontal line in the middle with using only CSS. Therefore, I reached the conclusion that the circle and the horizontal line must be two separate pseudo-elements.

In this case, the `::after` pseudo-element creates the circle part. Also, we use the `z-index` to make it so that the full circle appears only as semicircle because half of it is covered by `div.child`.

As for the horizontal line, we are still creating it using the `::before` pseudo-element. However, the line (from the parent's `border-left`) is protruding and we want to make the last trailing bit of the list-like line disappear. To do this, we can modify the last `div.child`'s `::before` pseudo-element so that it is instead a rectangle. Set its height to 50% of `div.child`, position it to 50% from the top of the `div.child`, make the `border-top` black to create the horizontal line, and make the `border-left` white to cover the parent's trailing line.

Here's a working example. I used `4px` on last `div.child::before` pseudo-element so that it doesn't draw wrongly upon zoom. Also, you might want to read about [`box-sizing: border-box` here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) (although unrelated).

```css
.parent {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  left: -20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  width: 20px;
}

.child::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  left: -5px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.child:last-child::before { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 4px solid #FFF;
  height: 50%;
  left: -22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    click to add more
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.child::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 90%;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r5z0av87/1/

Comment: thank you @Julian Paolo Dayag for your response, is  there a way we can trim the line where the container list ends (updated the screenshot) I tried various ways, but not helping. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  
}

.child::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -5px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.child::after{
    position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -20px;
  top: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  width: 20px;
}

.child:last-child::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -21px;
  top: calc(50% + 1px);
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    click to add more
  </div>
</div>
```

Add an `::before` element. Create an square. put `border-radius: 50%` so you have an circle. Then position the element at the right place. Put `z-index: -1` so that the circle is under your div block.

Use `calc` to calculate the vertical alignment. `calc(50% - 5px)` here i used 50% like for the lines and `5px` are the half of the width or height of the square.

For `left` i used `6px`. Usually `5px`, the half of the width, should be the exact half but i decided to go with `6px` kinda looks better for me, personal opinion.

```
.child::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -6px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```